# How to use Redux RTK Query with Supabase

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, supabase

Does anyone know how to use the Supabase Query pattern combined with RTK Query like for example https://dev.to/sruhleder/using-react-query-with-supabase-a03.

Comment: The example you refer to is `react-query` *not* `redux toolkit query`. These are two different software packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been banging my head against this for a while until I saw in the documentation that RTK Query expects the `data` not as a full object but [as a property](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#queryfn-function-return-value).

So the above code example needs to change the return value like the following:

```js
import { createApi, fakeBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/react';

const supabaseApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getTodos: builder.query({
      queryFn: async () => {
        const {data, error} = await supabase
          .from('todo')
          .select('id, name')
          .eq('done', false)

        if (error) {
          throw { error };
        }

        return { data };
      }
    })
  })
})

export const { useGetTodosQuery } = supabaseApi
export { supabaseApi }
```

Comment: Hello seems that fakeBaseQuery doe snot use cache Do you know how to activate it?

Comment: Hello @JonathanVargas, unfortunately I don't. It has been a while since I work with RTK 

Answer (score 7):

While I haven't used Supabase at all, it looks like it provides a Promise-based async request API.

In that case, you could use it with [RTK Query's `queryFn` endpoint option](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#implementing-a-queryfn), which lets you write your own arbitrary async logic and return whatever data you want.

While I haven't tested this code, a translation of the React Query + Supabase example to RTKQ might look like:

```js
import { createApi, fakeBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/react';

const supabaseApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getTodos: builder.query({
      queryFn: async () => {
        const {data, error} = await supabase
          .from('todo')
          .select('id, name')
          .eq('done', false)

        return data;
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share an improvement to the last answer to be able to handle errors with typescript and supabase. You can find the reference [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#examples---queryfn) and [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2824). I also checked that the cache still works.

supabase-base-query.ts

```
import type { BaseQueryFn } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query"
import { PostgrestError } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

const _NEVER = /* @__PURE__ */ Symbol()
export type NEVER = typeof _NEVER

/**
 * Creates a "fake" baseQuery to be used if your api *only* uses the `queryFn` definition syntax.
 * This also allows you to specify a specific error type to be shared by all your `queryFn` definitions.
 */
export const supabaseBaseQuery = (): BaseQueryFn<
  void,
  NEVER,
  PostgrestError,
  {}
> => {
  return function () {
    throw new Error(
      'When using `supabaseBaseQuery`, all queries & mutations must use the `queryFn` definition syntax.',
    )
  }
}
```

todo.ts

```
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/react';
import { supabaseBaseQuery } from "@/libs/supabase-base-query";
import { supabaseClient } from "@/libs/supabase";
import { Tables } from "src/types/supabase";

const todoApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: supabaseBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getTodos: builder.query<Tables<"todo">, void>({
      queryFn: async () => {
        const {data, error} = await supabase
          .from('todo')
          .select('id, name')
          .eq('done', false)

        if (error) {
          return { error };
        }

        return { data };
      }
    })
  })
})

export const { useGetTodosQuery } = todoApi
export { todoApi }
```

Extra script to generate types in src/types folder. It can be added into package.json as "generate-types": "node genSupaTypes.js" in the scripts section. [Reference](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/rest/generating-types)

genSupaTypes.js

```js
require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.development' });
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

try {
  execSync(`npx supabase gen types typescript --project-id ${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_PROJECT_ID} --schema public > src/types/supabase.ts`);
  console.log('Supabase types generated successfully!');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error generating Supabase types:', error);
}
```