# How to use RTK-Query with Supabase

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, supabase

I have a project already configured with Supabase and using Redux-Toolkit. I have never used RTK-Query and I am just learning but after reading in [the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#implementing-a-queryfn) and looking for [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70700188/how-to-use-redux-rtk-query-with-supabase/70700764#70700764) I have created a supabaseApi.js file which looks like:

```js
import { createApi, fakeBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';

export const supabaseApi = createApi({   baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
    endpoints: (builder) =({
        getStudents: builder.query({
            queryFn: async () ={
                const students = await supabase
                .from('students')
                .select()

                return {students, error}
            }
        })
    }) })

export const { useGetStudentsQuery } = supabaseApi;
```

However, when I call the useGetStudentsQuery() to get the students table I receive an error in the console telling me that "useGetStudentsQuery is not a function". I also noticed that when I begin to write the useGet function, it seems it hasn't been automatically created as I don't get the Visual Studio hints.

What is it that I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- to have the hooks, you have to `import` from `'@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';`
- the `queryFn` has to return either `{ data }` or `{ error }`, not `{ student }`
- your code does not seem to have a `error` variable, but tries to return it.

so:

```js
import { createApi, fakeBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const supabaseApi = createApi({   baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
    endpoints: (builder) =({
        getStudents: builder.query({
            queryFn: async () ={
                const students = await supabase
                .from('students')
                .select()

                return { data: students }
            }
        })
    }) })

export const { useGetStudentsQuery } = supabaseApi;
```